# Container for sip servlets?

Tags: servlets, sip, sip-server, sip-servlet, mobicents-sip-servlets

I am new to programming and working on SIP applications. I am bit confused about where to deploy SIP applications. I read about HTTP Servlets, which are deployed in servlet container, I believe Tomcat is one Servlet container.

Basically, I have few questions and understanding:

1. Container manages the lifecycle of the servlets and if I just get the servlets api jar and deploy it with my application it will not work?
2. I found SIP servlet API and there's also Mobicents SIP servlets. Are they different?
3. Can I deploy my SIP servlet application in Tomcat along with the API jar?
4. Is Mobicent a container for SIP servlets like Tomcat is for HTTP Servlets, but Mobicents also has Tomcat.

These are very naive questions but I tried to find out the answers myself and was not successful. I am not from programming background so having a difficulty to understand the things.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. I invite you to read the specification at https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=289 it's not a complex read and will give you a good idea of what you can do. SIP servlets are built off the generic servlet API provided by the Java Servlet Specification but differ from them in a number of ways notably on being asynchronous or being able to generate multiple responses to an incoming request
2. the SIP Servlets API is defined by the Java specification mentioned in 1. above. [Mobicents SIP Servlets](https://github.com/Mobicents/sip-servlets) is an implementation of the SIP Servlets API specification. It is supported by [TeleStax](http://www.telestax.com/). This is very similar in concept to JBoss Application Server (aka Wildfly) implementing the Java EE Specifications and being supported by Red Hat.
3. Please download the latest version of [Mobicents SIP Servlets on Tomcat](https://github.com/Mobicents/sip-servlets/releases). It comes with a couple SIP Servlets application by default. You can also check out [the examples](https://github.com/Mobicents/sip-servlets/tree/master/sip-servlets-examples), that should give you a good sense of how things are working together.
4. the SIP Servlets specification mandates convergence of SIP and HTTP so that you can use both in your application and share data between HTTP Sessions and SIP Sessions to create converged applications leveraging both the Web and the VoIP worlds. As such Mobicents SIP Servlets extends Tomcat to provide SIP capabilities to it. So a vanilla Tomcat installation will not support SIP Servlets out of the box, you need to download the specific extended Mobicents SIP Servlets Tomcat Version to be able to use SIP Servlets.

There is no naive questions ;)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I still have few doubts:
1. I found some tutorials which import some jar into the project to run the SIP servlets example. Does it mean that I can deploy the project to any app server?
2. I found **mjSIP**. Is it another implementation of SIP servlets or is it a SIP server built using SIP servlets API?
3. Mobicents Tomcat, it provides converged solution. So, is it modified version of original Tomcat or is it the case that I download the Tomcat from apache site and install the Mobicents SIP Servlet jar into it and it works fine.

I hope you understand my confusions.

Comment: 1. No, the app server has to support SIP Servlets. 2. No it doesn't seem to implement SIP Servlets and last release was from 2012, not sure it is still active. 3. We extend Tomcat core classes so you can't really download Tomcat from apache and install Mobicents as sometimes they break the backward compatibility in the internal API that we use to extend Tomcat.

Comment: One free option for development purposes (and small production deployments) that includes a JSR 289 SIP Servlet container is the latest WebSphere Liberty beta server. You can download it from www.wasdev.net. You'll need the extended package to get the SIP servlet 1.1 feature.

Comment: @jeand: I hope you can resolve this confusion too. Is the Presence Server at [link](http://docs.jboss.org/mobicents/sip-presence/1.0.0.CR1/user-guide/en-US/html/itsps-Installing_the_SIP_Presence_Service.html) is same as JBCP5.1 on redhat site [link](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Communications_Platform/5.0/pdf/SIP_Presence_Service_User_Guide/JBoss_Communications_Platform-5.0-SIP_Presence_Service_User_Guide-en-US.pdf). I confused because when I search for mobicents presence server both the links appear? Somebody referred me to the former source but I found the later also.

Comment: A little bit of background here. Mobicents is the open source community project. JBCP stands for JBoss Communications Platform which was the product from Red Hat derived from Mobicents on which Red Hat was selling support services from 2007 to 2011. Red Hat stopped selling JBCP in 2011. TeleStax is the company now selling products derived from Mobicents under the name TelScale for long term support. The Presence Service project has been somewhat in a dormant stage for multiple reasons, one being that since 2011, RCS/Joyn entered the picture but couldn't successfully competing with OTT players.

Comment: @jeand: Thanks Jean. You are of great help.

Comment: @jeand: Sorry for troubling you but not able to find much help elsewhere. I have installed the Mobicents Presence Server integrated but now not being able to proceed. Trying to register the softphones but timing out. I just followed the guide. I have asked the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30786593/mobicents-presence-server-how-to-register-softphone) for the same too .