# Mobicents presence server. How to register softphone?

Tags: sip, user-presence, mobicents, mobicents-sip-servlets

I have installed the Mobicents Presence server following the [guide](https://docs.jboss.org/mobicents/sip-presence/1.0.0.FINAL/user-guide/html_single/).

The server is installed but now I am not able to proceed further. I mean now how to test the presence or register the devices with XDM, PS and RLS. How do I find on which port the services are running?

I am able to see register messages received to the server but on the softphones request timeouts.

Is there any documentation which I am missing?

Please help.

Comment: Were you able to move ahead? Did you installed from the source??

Answer (score 1):

The Mobicents SIP Presence Server is not supported anymore.
There is an issue on GitHub currently in development about presence. Take a look at: https://github.com/Mobicents/RestComm/issues/380