# Mobicent Presence Service Installation

Tags: sip, user-presence, mobicents

I am trying to install Mobicents Presence Service on Windows and Ubuntu but there is no clear documentation I could find. There are some on jboss and redhat site, which are same and few are for the beta versions. What I see is that the folder structure and few deployment file names do not match in those documents and current download.

I basically need to build from source and for that also not able to follow the documentation.

I have searched a lot in google, google groups and SO but really not able to find any help.

Is there any document available for the installation?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The Mobicents SIP Presence Server is not supported anymore. There is an issue on GitHub currently in development about presence. Take a look at: https://github.com/Mobicents/RestComm/issues/380

Original answer: [Mobicents presence server. How to register softphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30786593/mobicents-presence-server-how-to-register-softphone)

Comment: Thanks for the update. Anyways, I was able to install it.